# How to create a Mat on OpenCV for making an histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

I'm making kind of an histogram stored in a Matrix on OpenCV.

So, if I match one result, I will at +1 on some index.

My mat is:

`Mat countFramesMatrix = Mat::zeros(9,9,CV_8U);`

when I try to access to sum +1 to the already set index (from 0), I do:

```
int valueMatrixFrames = countFramesMatrix.at<int>(sliceMatch.j, sliceMatch.i);
valueMatrixFrames++;
countFramesMatrix.at<unsigned char>(sliceMatch.j, sliceMatch.i) = (unsigned char)valueMatrixFrames;
```

I tried in other ways, as changing `unsigned char` for `int` an other problems I had before, but nothing happens.

My results are:

1. Or all the matrix is zeros.
2. Or I get something like:

   `[2.3693558e-38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    2.3693558e-38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

And I'm never storing data at (0,0) or (0,1) or (1,0) or (1,1), :(

What would you suggest? thank you.

Comment: How is declared countFramesMatrix ? You access to this matrix sometime telling the compiler this is a matrix of int, sometime telling it is a matrix of char. Technically, this is not forbiden to do so, but I doubt this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misting a very simple mistake,

```
valueMatrixFrames++;
```

will increment value of `valueMatrixFrames`, not of the matrix location.

**RIGHT WAY**

Let's say, if you want to increment at (1,1) you should use,

```
countFramesMatrix.at<uchar>(1,1)++;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Running the above command again will increment the value at (1, 1) to 2.

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So, your histogram is ready!!

Comment: Yes, I was doing `valueMatrixFrames++` but then I was assigning it to my matrix, so the logic was correct. The thing I was missing is the `uchar` thing. Thank you very much ;)